# Is there a more modern regexp handler for Open Object Rexx?

Tags: regex, pcre, rexx

The regular expression class (rxregexp.dll) that comes with ooRexx (I'm on 4.0.0) is relatively low on functions compared, say, with Python's re module (even at 2.5.2).

It appears to have no assertions, no facilities for group extraction, or for substitution. Greedy or lazy matching is a global pattern option, rather than flagged by an additional "?". Basically, a pre-PCRE regular expression engine.

Does anyone know if anything with more up-to-date function is available?

Comment: Apologies for the careless tagging, and thanks @gf for the fix.

Comment: Based on the huge response to your question, I would guess the answer is no! Have you tried the comp.lang.rexx news group - I think that is where a lot of the ooREXX related conversations are held. I took a quick look and there doesn't seem to be anything recent concerning regex.

Comment: Also look at www.oorexx.org.  Their fora are members only, but finding a member is not too hard <wink>,